# How do I export data from a Query to a text file with fixed column widths?

Tags: sql, ssis

Am I the only person who thinks SSIS is a piece of *****?

I have a query:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
```

And I want to do is put this into a text file with specific lengths in the destination file (I have specs from a client).

For example, Field 1 size: 20, field 2 size: 3, and so on.

I also have the field positions, Field 1: 1-20, Field 2: 21-23, etc.

I created an SSIS package that has a source as a SQL query and a flat file as the destination. I CANNOT FOR THE LIFE OF ME GET THIS TO WORK.

The data on the text file is all messed up (its scattered all over the place, no columns).

This is the simplest task in the world and I cannot do it. I don't know if it's me or if SSIS is just a piece of crap.

Comment: Cast each field individually to varchar of required size?

Comment: should I do "Fixed width with row delimiters" or "ragged right?"

Comment: Ragged right is for when you have a variable number of columns on each row. What exact output configuration have you used in your file? As already stated, make sure you are not in a text editor that automatically wraps - the data might all be on one line.

Yes SSIS can be a pain. It's not all it's cracked up to be. You might find you need to export it as one pre formatted line as suggested below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the Connection Manager you defined for your flat file.  In the left box, select  General and set the Format to "Fixed Width".  Then in the left box, select Advanced and here you can set the OutputColumnWidth for each field.  Lastly, in the left box, select Preview to verify the results before executing the SSIS package.

Hope this helps.
Kosh

Comment: values are scattered throughout the txt file. I think its because its not putting a new line after the last column. also, i have the format set to "Fixed width"

Comment: Are you viewing the output file in NotePad? I have a text file that makes the values appear wrapped in NotePad (even when Word Wrap is not checked). But when I open it in Excel, everything falls in place and looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

I actually just did this last week. I wrote a function that does this then for each field I call the function.

Here is the function

```
/*
USE [Newton-Dev]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[CharPad]    Script Date: 1/10/2015 11:38:27 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
/*
Script  : Character Padding Function; Assist with fixed width file creation
Version : 1.0 (01/08/2015)
Author  : Jeffery Williams

*/
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[CharPad] (
     @Input VARCHAR(255)
    ,@OutputWidth INT
    ,@OutputAlign VARCHAR(5)
    ,@PadCharacter CHAR(1) )
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Output VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @InputWidth INT

SET @InputWidth = LEN(@Input)

IF @InputWidth > @OutputWidth
    BEGIN 
        IF @OutputAlign = 'LEFT'
            BEGIN
            SET @Output = LEFT(@Input,@OutputWidth)
            END
        IF @OutputAlign = 'RIGHT'
            BEGIN
            SET @Output = RIGHT(@Input,@OutputWidth)
            END
    END

IF @InputWidth < @OutputWidth 
    BEGIN 
        IF @OutputAlign = 'RIGHT'
            BEGIN
            SET @Output = REPLICATE(@PadCharacter, @OutputWidth - @InputWidth ) + @Input
            END
        IF @OutputAlign = 'LEFT'
            BEGIN
            SET @Output =@Input+ REPLICATE(@PadCharacter, @OutputWidth - @InputWidth )
            END
    END

IF @InputWidth = @OutputWidth 
    SET @Output = @Input

RETURN (@Output)
END
```

Here is the query that calls the function and provides the fixed width output:

```
SELECT --dbo.CharPad (DeltaLineId,8,'LEFT',' '), dbo.CharPad (DeltaElgId,8,'LEFT',' ')
       dbo.CharPad (CARRIER_ID,6,'LEFT',' ')
       ,dbo.CharPad (GROUP_NUM,7,'RIGHT','0')
      ,dbo.CharPad (LEFT('0000' + SUB_GROUP_ID, 4),9,'LEFT',' ')
      ,dbo.CharPad (SVC_TYPE,1,'LEFT',' ')
      ,dbo.CharPad (FILLER_1,1,'LEFT',' ')
      ,dbo.CharPad (FILLER_2,5,'LEFT',' ') 
      ,dbo.CharPad (RATE_CODE,2,'LEFT',' ')
      ,dbo.CharPad (FILLER_3,1,'LEFT',' ')
      ,dbo.CharPad (ELIG_CODE,1,'LEFT',' ')
      ,dbo.CharPad (EFF_DATE,8,'LEFT',' ') 
      ,dbo.CharPad (TERM_DATE,8,'LEFT',' ') 
      ,dbo.CharPad (SUBSC_SSN,9,'LEFT',' ')  
      ,dbo.CharPad (INDIV_SSN,9,'LEFT',' ') 
      ,dbo.CharPad (CHNG_SSN,9,'LEFT',' ')   
      ,dbo.CharPad (REL_CODE,2,'LEFT',' ') 
      ,dbo.CharPad (HIRE_DATE,8,'LEFT',' ')  
      ,dbo.CharPad (DOB,8,'LEFT',' ') 
      ,dbo.CharPad (REL_TYPE,1,'LEFT',' ')  
      ,dbo.CharPad (FIRST_NAME,24,'LEFT',' ') 
      ,dbo.CharPad (MID_NAME,24,'LEFT',' ')                 
      ,dbo.CharPad (LAST_NAME,24,'LEFT',' ') 
      ,dbo.CharPad (GENDER,1,'LEFT',' ')  
      ,dbo.CharPad (POP_DESC,5,'LEFT',' ') 
      ,dbo.CharPad (ADR_LINE_1,30,'LEFT',' ')                      
      ,dbo.CharPad (ADR_LINE_2,30,'LEFT',' ') 
      ,dbo.CharPad (CITY,30,'LEFT',' ')                           
      ,dbo.CharPad ([STATE],2,'LEFT',' ') 
      ,dbo.CharPad (COUNTY_CODE,3,'LEFT',' ')  
      ,dbo.CharPad (COUNTRY_CODE,3,'LEFT',' ') 
      ,dbo.CharPad (ZIP,5,'LEFT',' ')    
      ,dbo.CharPad (ZIP_EXT,4,'LEFT',' ') 
      ,dbo.CharPad (FILLER_4,21,'LEFT',' ')               
      ,dbo.CharPad (USER_DEFINED,30,'LEFT',' ') 
      ,dbo.CharPad (WAIT_PERIOD,1,'LEFT',' ')  
      ,dbo.CharPad (CAID,9,'RIGHT','0') 
      ,dbo.CharPad (FILLER_5,9,'LEFT',' ') 
FROM export.DeltaLine

*/
```

Comment: This appears to be what I need for the details section of my report. Thanks, however do you know how I can get a header record (row) in the same file that has different start and end positions and still requires certain items to be left and right justified? I was thinking that I might have to create two files and then manually add the header record. Any ideas on how to combine everything into one file from the beginning would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a solid answer.  I'd suggest a modification to the function to handle nulls being passed in.  I like this approach rather than burying the logic in some SSIS package somewhere.  It also has the benefit of being reusable.

Answer (score 0):

To adjust Jeff's procedure to handle nulls, make these replacements.
Instead of:

```
SET @InputWidth = LEN(@Input)
```

Use:

```
SET @InputWidth = Isnull(@Input,REPLICATE(' ',@OutputWidth)
```

And instead of:

```
SET @Output = @Input
```

Use:

```
SET @Output = Isnull(@Input,REPLICATE(' ',@OutputWidth)
```